# How do I set the default terminal type for launch configurations in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I followed the official instructions to create a launch object in my user settings:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_global-launch-configuration

```
{
    "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "window.titleBarStyle": "native",
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "never",
    "editor.autoClosingQuotes": "never",
    "java.configuration.checkProjectSettingsExclusions": false,
    "java.errors.incompleteClasspath.severity": "ignore",
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "terminal.external.linuxExec": "gnome-terminal",
    "terminal.explorerKind": "external",
    "launch": {
        "configurations": [
            {
                "console": "externalTerminal"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

When I run a file with these settings, the generated launch.json looks like this:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "CodeLens (Launch) - Dreieck",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "de.ostfalia.gdp.ss19.s2.Dreieck",
            "projectName": "gdp"
        },
        {
            "console": "externalTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

This second block doesn't have any effect, the code still runs on the default debug console.

It should generate a file that looks like this:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "CodeLens (Launch) - Dreieck",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "de.ostfalia.gdp.ss19.s2.Dreieck",
            "projectName": "gdp",
            "console": "externalTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there anything I can do to make vscode generate working launch files like this?